# How can I create a rectangle that is split vertically in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In tikz, a `rectangle split` node is split horizontally. According to [a comment by Mark Wibrow on 2008-04-21](http://www.texample.net/tikz/builds/), it is possible to create rectangle nodes that are split vertically. However, I can't find how to do that in the tikz manual or in the online examples. Does sm here know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the TikZ manual (version 2.10, section 48.6.  Page 451, but see the example on page 450) the boolean option `rectangle split horizontal` will toggle this.  Do you have this (the current) version of TikZ?

Comment: This worked, thanks. Turns out that I was looking at an older version of the manual, because googling for "tikz manual" shows a link for version 1.18.